# install additional Enterprise Subordinate CA

Tags: ad-certificate-services, pki

I have already set up a working two tier Active Directory Certificate Services PKI hierarchy with an offline standalone Root CA (ROOT-CA) and one online Enterprise Subordinate CA (ISSUING-CA). For redundancy I would like to add an additional Subordinate CA. For this second Subordinate CA, can I use the same certificate (ISSUING-CA) to issue new certificates as I do on the first Subordinate CA? Or do I need to request a new one (ISSUING-CA-02) specific for this server?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a different CA name and CA certificate. ADCS Certification Authority does not support NLB, only failover cluster (with active/passive nodes).